# pandas memory error after a certain skiprows parameter

Tags: python, pandas, memory

I have a ~1.81GB CSV file which has ~49m rows. It has only one column that contains 38-character strings.

I am reading this file with `read_csv` on a Digital Ocean VPS (Ubuntu 12.04.4, Python 2.7, pandas 0.18.0, 512MB RAM). I read 5000 lines at a time. However, it started raising errors at `skiprows = 2800000`. Here's the code I'm testing on a rebooted computer, freshly started Python:

```
>>> pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=2800000, nrows=5000, header=None)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ayhan/.conda/envs/swrm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 529, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/ayhan/.conda/envs/swrm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 295, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/home/ayhan/.conda/envs/swrm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 608, in __init__
    self.options, self.engine = self._clean_options(options, engine)
  File "/home/ayhan/.conda/envs/swrm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 731, in _clean_options
    skiprows = set() if skiprows is None else set(skiprows)
MemoryError
```

If I run it with `skiprows=1000000` it works fine. If I try `skiprows=1500000` it raises the error again, which is strange because the error started after reaching 2800000. It went through every 5000 multipliers before that with no problem. Any idea why this happens?

The code works fine on my personal computer:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=2800000, nrows=5000, header=None)

df.memory_usage()
Out[25]: 
Index       72
0        40000
dtype: int64
```

Edit:

The original loop goes like this:

```
current_chunk = 560 
chnksize = 5000

for chunk in range(current_chunk, 1000):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=chnksize*chunk, nrows=chnksize, header=None)
    out = "chunk_" + format(chunk, "06d")
    short_ids = df[0].str.slice(-11)
```

It queries the short_id from an API and appends the result to a file. But the code piece I gave at the top raises the error by itself.

Comment: can you show your loop?

Comment: Use the code formatting button for error messages, not the quote button.

Comment: @MaxU I added the loop (well sort of, original loop was quite long so I added the part where I isolated the error) -- user2357112 fixed it.

Comment: @ayhan, you are misusing `skiprows` parameter, you should be using `chunksize`

Comment: @MaxU It was actually my own unsuccessful implementation, that's why the typo. I knew that I could read chunk by chunk with pandas' function but I didn't know that I could access a certain chunk so I was using skiprows.

Comment: @ayhan, i know, it's not always easy to find in pandas docs how to use some features ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas is using a bafflingly memory-intensive way of implementing `skiprows`. In [`pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader._clean_options`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py#L778):

```
if com.is_integer(skiprows):
    skiprows = lrange(skiprows)
skiprows = set() if skiprows is None else set(skiprows)
```

`lrange(n)` does `list(range(n))`, so this is basically doing `skiprows = set(list(range(skiprows)))`. It's building two giant lists and a set, each containing 2.8 million integers! I suppose they never expected people to try to skip so many rows.

---

If you want to read through a file in chunks, calling `read_csv` repeatedly with different values of `skiprows` is an inefficient way to do it. You can pass `read_csv` a `chunksize` option and then iterate over the returned `TextFileReader` in chunks:

```
In [138]: reader = pd.read_table('tmp.sv', sep='|', chunksize=4)

In [139]: reader
Out[139]: <pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader at 0x121159a50>

In [140]: for chunk in reader:
   .....:     print(chunk)
   .....: 
   Unnamed: 0         0         1         2         3
0           0  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
1           1  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2           2 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
3           3  0.721555 -0.706771 -1.039575  0.271860
   Unnamed: 0         0         1         2         3
0           4 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
1           5 -0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
2           6  0.404705  0.577046 -1.715002 -1.039268
3           7 -0.370647 -1.157892 -1.344312  0.844885
   Unnamed: 0         0        1         2         3
0           8  1.075770 -0.10905  1.643563 -1.469388
1           9  0.357021 -0.67460 -1.776904 -0.968914
```

or pass `iterator=True` and use `get_chunk` to get chunks of specified sizes:

```
In [141]: reader = pd.read_table('tmp.sv', sep='|', iterator=True)

In [142]: reader.get_chunk(5)
Out[142]: 
   Unnamed: 0         0         1         2         3
0           0  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
1           1  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2           2 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
3           3  0.721555 -0.706771 -1.039575  0.271860
4           4 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
```

Comment: Now that I'm done with those 2.8m rows, is there a way to skip a number of chunks? Do I need to call get_chunk(chunksize) n times to skip n chunks?

Comment: @ayhan: I'm not aware of any better way to do it. You could pass a larger chunk size, but that's likely to run into memory problems again.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `skiprows` doesn't prevent to load data in memory, giving you a memory error. for your problem, you must use the [`chunk`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk)  parameter of `read_csv`, instead of `nrows`.

Comment: has this been updated in the new versions?